# On the 'reverse theorem' for functional equation of the Riemann zeta function

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-explanation, improper-integrals, riemann-zeta

The following is the first part of Section 2.13. of Titchmarsh's book *The Theory of the Riemann Zeta-Function*:

[image]

My **first** question (orange-underlined) is: How $R_{\nu} = x^{-\frac12 s_{\nu}} Q_{\nu}(\log x)$ holds? I mean, why we can write each $Q_{\nu}(x)$ as a *polynomial* with indeterminate $\log x$?

The rest of the section is as follows:

[image: ---]

My **second** question (blue-underlined) is: how to prove that $\int_0^{\infty} x^a \log^b(x) e^{ - \pi t^2 x} dx$ is a sum of the terms of the form $t^{\alpha} \log^{\beta}(x)$? Again, [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate%20x%5Ea%20%5Cln%28x%29%5Eb%20e%5E%7B%20-%20%5Cpi%20t%5E2%20x%7D%20dx) couldn't help!

Question **Three** (pink-underlined): The LHS includes $-\pi \sum_{k=1}^{m} t^{\alpha_k +1} \log^{\beta}(x).$ How replacing $t$ with $t+i$ leaves the expression unchanged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The $\log x$ would come into play if you'd have a pole of order $2$ or greater. So basically to get to $R_1$ you expand everything into power series around $s_1$ and multiply out and collect the $-1$ coefficient, so you could get $\log x$ terms from $x^{-s/2}=e^{-\frac
   {\log x}{2}s}$.
2. Just substitute to pull out the $t's$ from the integral.
3. The LHS should be periodic, not each term of the LHS. Think about what you would get if you'd replace $f$ with $\zeta$.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151002/discussion-on-answer-by-eulersgroupie-on-the-reverse-theorem-for-functional-eq); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.